# Subsequence of Laguerre polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, laguerre

Let $m\geqslant1$ be a fixed integer.

Let  $f(n)$ be [A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814), the exponent of the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, a.k.a. the binary carry sequence, the ruler sequence, or the $2$-adic valuation of $n$.

Then we have an integer sequence given by
\begin{align}
a(0)&=1\\
a(n)& = ma\left(\frac{n-2^{f(n)}}{2}\right)+(-1)^{n}a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n-2^{f(n)}}{2}\right\rfloor\right)
\end{align}
I conjecture that
$$a\left(\frac{4^n-1}{3}\right)=m^{n}n!L_{n}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$$
where $L_{n}(x)$ is Laguerre polynomials.

I also conjecture that $a(2^p(2^q-1))$ relates with $(p+1)$-Stirling numbers of the second kind, but I have problems with offset.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you for comment! Done.